# How can i resolve this npm errror?

Tags: npm, npm-install

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SINSY.png)

I am doing npm run update and got this error, (unable to update local ref 
npm run pull also did not work .

Comment: The image appears to suggest there's a problem with git as well as npm. Did you try `git reset` first?

Comment: git reset what it will do?

Comment: What is the exact command?

Comment: How can i navigate to this folder??
.git/refs/remotes/origin/

Comment: Does your package.json contain some `hydra-dev`?

Comment: Please add your `package.json` as well.

Comment: Does your package.json contain some hydra-dev? 
Yes it contains.

Comment: My Project name i hydra-dev. And i have some repositories inside my Project.

Comment: Ok. Try the steps in my answer

Answer (score 0):

Try these steps. Go to the directory where your package.json resides.

1. `git reset --hard`
2. Delete `node-modules`
3. Delete `package.lock.json` if there's any (don't delete package.json by mistake btw)
4. `npm install`

Comment: i dont want to delete node-modules, is there any other way??

Comment: error: cannot lock ref 'refs/remotes/origin/feature/WIN-3439-Adapter-For-HOO-Card': is at eee9375782d929203b10f58e0371b4254158407d but expected 8a7066e8320f6267c98fb82c48c3e685098f2e5f
 ! 8a7066e83..199be766f  feature/WIN-3439-Adapter-For-HOO-Card -> origin/feature/WIN-3439-Adapter-For-HOO-Card  (unable to update local ref)

Got this error when i tried to update repository from sourcetree.

Comment: You need to delete index.lock in your .git folder. Then Try the steps from step 1

Comment: And what’s the problem in deleting node_modules? I recommend deleting it because it might be corrupted due to the failed installation at first.